# Django Authentication System Implementation

Tags: python, django

I'm building a Django App and I want to implement authentication. I thought since the framework already includes a package, I would not have to complicate too much. But I'm finding a problem. Whenever I create a model | database Django creates the table for me. But since I haven't created any table, I suppose it's normal that Django raises `no such table: auth_user` when I try to work with the model.

I just wrote this code:

```
from django.contrib import auth
result = auth.authenticate(username=user,password=pswd)
```

Didn't do anything else. 
What do I have to write | execute for Django to create the table and start working with this built-in tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authenticate function wont log the user in, it just returns a user object if the credentials are correct.  You'll also have to use login.

`from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login`

then when the user is loging in:

```
user = authenticate(username=user, password=pswd)
if user is not None:
    #This will actually log the user in to the web request
    login(request, user)
```

More can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests

Comment: Ok yes but it return an error. I want to first solve this, can you help please? Thanks!

Comment: I am telling you in the question. The same happens when I try to create an user

Comment: Ahah!! That was it. I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Also make sure that 'django.contrib.auth' is within your INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Yes that was it. Thanks. I forgot to sync. Oh god I feel stupid.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you do not have the django auth module in the INSTALLED apps.

In your settings.py file check if the INSTALLED_APPS has

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...,
)
```

If not add `django.contrib.auth` to your INSTALLED_APPS and run `python manage.py syncb` to create the auth tables for you.

Note you might be asked to create an Admin user.

Comment: Thanks too, but Jordan already explained to me what I should do.

Comment: Yeah, saw Jordan's reply after posting it.